# Searching query in orders to selecting entries which have not any related entry

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Suppose there are 3 tables

bet Table:

```
betID
oddID
```

odd Table:

```
oddID
forecastID
```

forecast Table:

```
forecastID
```

I can not imagine select query for odds which have a forecastID which any odds of related to this forecast had not shown from any bet.

For example this is selecting the only forecastIDs which i souldnt select; by other word forecastID's which have related betIDs.

```
SELECT forecast.forecastID,betID FROM forecast INNER JOIN odd ON odd.forecastID = forecast.forecastID INNER JOIN bet ON bet.oddID = odd.oddID ;
```

Comment: change it to a LEFT JOIN for your bet table. and then add WHERE betID = null

Comment: what john said except change it to `IS NULL`

Comment: Can a single forecastID have more than one oddID?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT 
forecast.forecastID FROM forecast INNER JOIN odd ON odd.forecastID = forecast.forecastID LEFT JOIN bet ON bet.oddID = odd.oddID WHERE betID IS NULL;`

In this situation it is continuing to select forecast which have related bets becasuse they have odds which are related bets and also they have odds which have not any bet. I must select; which ones have not any related bet.

@BrianDeMilia: Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a single forecastID can have more than one oddID:

```
select distinct forecastid
  from odd
 where forecastid not in
       (select forecastid from odd join bet on bet.oddid = odd.oddid)
```

Comment: `(select forecastid from odd where exists (select 1 from bet where bet.oddid = odd.oddid));` is working fine to finding whic will not in BUT `select distinct forecastid from odd where forecast.forecastid not in (select forecastid from odd where exists (select 1 from bet where bet.oddid = odd.oddid));` is so slow or it is not working. I don't realize the reason

Comment: @orcungumus try my edit, uses just a join rather than an exists. Does that run any faster?